# How to identify webelements in ReactJS which has random classname

Tags: javascript

I have been automating a reactjs based page. The classname for the webelements are coming from react components and as expected they are updating often. Can someone help me with the best approach to identify those webelements

[snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmAid.png)

Comment: Please update the question with the code you already tried.

Comment: @CosminStaicu I just picked the xpath like `//div[@name='anchor-gainerslosers']//table[contains(@class,'styles__TableContainer')]//thead//div[contains(@class,'Text-sc')]`. This is not the best way and might become obsolete in the future